# C++ - Access All Functions Of Private Member Variable

Tags: c++

I get the feeling that this is a duplicate/stupid question, but, despite my best efforts, I don't know what to Google to find anything.

Anyhow, I would like to have a class `BigClass` that contains another class `SmallerClass` as a private member variable so that people using `BigClass`can't access the public member variables that `SmallerClass` contains.

However, I also want people to be able to manipulate `SmallerClass` via it's public methods. I want to be able call `bigClassInstance.SmallerClassMethod()` without having to make a bunch of methods inside `BigClass` that just call a homonymous method inside `SmallerClass`.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Note: I did consider getting `BigClass` to inherit from `SmallerClass`, but, this doesn't work as other things that are accessing `SmallerClass` directly need to manipulate `SmallerClass` as-is

EDIT:
I'm making a `Collider` class which is more or less a wrapper class around a Box2D body. I'm working with other people, and I want them to avoid touching the `b2Vec2` class whenever possible, in favour of a custom vector class that we're using. With the `Collider` doing conversions between `b2Vec2`s and our vectors to maintain consistency.

I didn't make this vague to be annoying, I was just trying to generalise it so that I didn't get Box2D only answers and not be able to apply what I learned to a different problem

Comment: Please show code to define the classes you are describing. Label the things you want accessable. Also read up on "protected" and "friend", it might help you find your own answer.

Comment: Is the subclass under your control? I.e. can you make its methods/attributes from public to protect or private?

Comment: @Yunnosch no, the subclass belongs to a third party library

Comment: When you say "other things that are accessing SmallerClass directly need to manipulate SmallerClass as-is" do you mean that other part of your code access the `SmallerClass` object stored *inside* the `BigClass` object? Or are they *independent* `SmallerClass` objects?

Comment: Add info to the question itself by [edit]ing please.

Comment: Also, remember that non-private inheritance is an "is-a" relationship. If your `BigClass` inherit from `SmallerClass` then `BigClass` **is** a `SmallerClass`. A pointer to a `BigClass` object can be implicitly converted to a pointer to a `SmallerClass`.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much going to be limited to one of the following:

- write a getter in BigClass that returns a reference to SmallClass (and call methods via that reference).
- write small inline methods in BigClass that thunk the call into SmallClass (probably the simplest and best solution).
- Use inheritance (which may or maynot be a good idea, depending on scenario)

Comment: The second way is the way to go, I think. Using way number one breaks the data hiding principle that you want to enforce by making the member private. And unless BigClass "is a" SmallClass, inheritance is no good idea.